# How do I run Google script on multiple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've seen this question return quite a few results here, but I'm having trouble getting it to work for my use case. Basically, I have a simple script that I want to run on multiple sheets in my spreadsheet (not every sheet, just the ones I define). I've tried defining the sheets and running a `for` loop, but it fails when calling the method getRange. Anyway, here's my original script that defines only one sheet, and this works as expected:

```js
var sheetToSort = "Sheet1";
var columnToSortBy = 1;
var rangeToSort = "A2:AB";

function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy && sheet.getName() == sheetToSort) {
    sortFormResponsesSheet();
  }
}

function sortFormResponsesSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToSort);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of putting settings into an object and then looping through the object.

```
function onEdit() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell(),
        editedColumn = editedCell.getColumn(),
        sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // Define all the sheets to sort using an object literal
  const objSheetsToSort = {
    "Sheet1": {columnToSortBy: 1, rangeToSort: "A2:AB"},
    "Sheet2": {columnToSortBy: 2, rangeToSort: "A2:AB"},
    "Sheet3": {columnToSortBy: 3, rangeToSort: "A2:AB"},
    "Sheet4": {columnToSortBy: 4, rangeToSort: "A2:AB"}
  }

  // Get the sort info for this sheet (or `undefined` if we didn't define how to sort the edited sheet).
  var config = objSheetsToSort[sheetName];
  if (config && editedColumn === config.columnToSortBy) {
    // We want to sort the edited sheet.
    sortSheet_(sheet, config);
  }
}

// This function can only be called by other functions in this Script Project, not manually or via menu.
function sortSheet_(sheetToSort, objectOfSettings) {
  Logger.log('sheetToSort: ' + sheetToSort.getName())

  var range = sheetToSort.getRange(objectOfSettings.rangeToSort);
  range.sort( { column : objectOfSettings.columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}
```

Comment: So I get two errors: "columnToSortBy" is not defined for the onEdit function, and for `var range = sheet.getRange(objectOfSettings.rangeToSort)` cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Comment: @brandon Couple of issues with this answer's implementation, but the idea is fine. Create an object that defines how and what to sort. Check if the edit was to something that exists in your object. If so, use that object info to sort.

Comment: I made a couple of changes.  Hopefully it's closer to what you want.

Comment: The onedit function executes properly now, however I still get the same error with the getRange method under the sortFormReponsesSheet function

Comment: I added two `Logger.log()` statements.  Run the code and then in the code editor, click the View menu, and then choose Logs.  That error probably means that `sheet` is not being assigned to the sheet class, which means that the sheet name is either missing or wrong.

Comment: I thought the same as well, so I triple checked to make sure everything was spelled correctly, and it is. The logger gave me sheetToSort: undefined

Comment: If it's undefined then it's not getting passed in.  If it's not getting passed in, then there is something wrong with how the function is getting called.  I made some more changes to the code.  Changed `k` to `sheetName`

Comment: Why not just pass the `sheet` object directly? Avoid the "sheet -> name -> spreadsheet -> get sheet with name" path entirely?

Comment: Still says undefined. I'll keep trying to troubleshoot, and report back with whatever I find. @tehhowch admittedly my knowledge of javascript is really basic, so just bare with me if a suggestions or terminology goes over my head.

Comment: @tehhowch Just saw that you edited Sandy Good's answer. The logger line fails because "getName" is undefined. Even removing the logger line, "getRange" is still undefined. I'm really not sure what's going on. When using my original script, everything executes properly. So I'm definitely not missing something in that respect.

Comment: @Brandon, are you attempting to run `sortFormResponsesSheet` manually? That won't work, because manually running it does not pass the required arguments `sheetToSort` or `objectOfSettings`. (Also note that you are misreading the error messages you are getting - those error messages state that you cannot call the method `getRange` / `getName` of `undefined`, not that `getRange` / `getName` are `undefined`. That message means that `sheetToSort` - the thing you are calling those methods on - is `undefined`.)

Comment: Ah of course, that makes a lot of sense now. So in that case, yes, it's working now after I triggered the function on a form response. I imagine Sandy's would have worked as well. Thanks to both of you for working through this with me. I've definitely learned a lot.