# Google Sheets Hide Rows Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this whole script coding thing and am having trouble refining a script I currently have running. I found the code I'm using [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5Hdtjc7DAI0). I was able to modify it to run on column E of my worksheet and it works beautifully on that one sheet.

I'd like to have it run on multiple sheets in the workbook but I'm not familiar enough with the coding language/syntax to make it work. I've tried pulling bits of code from other posts with a similar goal, only to have the script error on a part of the code that was working previously.

The code is as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName('BV421');
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    s.getRange('E:E')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, d) {
            if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
                .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(d + 1)
        });
}
```

I know the problem (at least in part) is with the .getSheetByName('BV421') but I'm not sure how to get it to select multiple sheets. I have other sheets (e.g., Alexafluor488, PerCP, FITC, etc.) that I would like to run the script on but not all of the sheets in the workbook.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google script to work across multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360229/google-script-to-work-across-multiple-sheets)

Comment: Related: [How do I run Google script on multiple sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626396/1595451)

Comment: Hi Matt, you can get multiple sheets in GAS using SpreadsheetApp.getSheets(). This will return an array of all your sheets. You can then loop through them and manipulate them. Will put a bit of some code for you as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Code 2:**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ['BV421', 'Alexafluor488', 'PerCP', 'FITC'].forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    // here do everything you need with the sheet s
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    s.getRange('E:E').getValues().forEach(function (r, d) {
      if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString().charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(d + 1);
    });
  });
}
```

You can repeat the code fragment for each sheet listed in array, if you get the sheet reference - **s**.

Answer (score 0):

### Sample Code:

```
    function getSheets(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Gets the Spreadsheet
    var sheets = ss.getSheets(); //Gets all the sheets in the spreadsheet

      //For the number of sheets, do the following:
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){

      var currentSheet = sheets[i];

      Logger.log(currentSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValue());


      }

    }
```

If you don't want to start at the first sheet, change the value of "i".
If you don't want the script to go over all sheets, change sheets.length to a fixed value.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Other members please feel free to edit this post to add links to documentation or just explain it better. (Have work I need to attend to.)

Comment: Thanks @New_2_Code! When I insert the code (though admittedly I'm not sure where to insert it) I get the error "cannot find function showRows in objectSpreadsheet." I'm probably royally screwing the code up but I'm a total newb.